# Powershell on SCOM script, Capture output for field -Owner

Tags: powershell, scom

Simple question i believe, but cant understand why my single liner do not print any output. I want ot filter Objects only with resolutions state (0 = new), and Owner area which is blank (not assigned). So i thoght that if it will be null, or i am understadnign not correctly. Thanks for any advice.

```
Get-SCOMAlert -ComputerName dbdtScomProd | Where-Object {$_.ResolutionState -eq “0” -and $_.Owner -eq “NULL”}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a null value in a where-object statement, use

```
Get-SCOMAlert -ComputerName dbdtScomProd | Where-Object {$_.ResolutionState -eq “0” -and $_.Owner -eq $null}
```

You may also want to look at using `Get-SCOMAlert -Criteria`

As an example:

```
Get-SCOMAlert -Criteria "ResolutionState = 0 AND Owner IS NULL"}
```

Using `Measure-Command` in my environment, I see Criteria take 0.6 Seconds and the `Where-Object` command take 5.1 Seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! thanks. I definetly will try to dig deeper in these commands, thanks for advices, and solution!

Comment: Happy to help!  It's very helpful to browse TechNet.Microsoft.Com for powershell commands, often there are articles written by Microsoft that offer TONS of helpful tips!

Comment: I am trying to google it, and reading microsoft technet, but not all the time everything can understand. And then i am stuck, i am asking for this community to help :)

Comment: What is helpful to me is using PowerShell's help `Get-Help Get-SCOMAlert -Full` to see the examples, then searching for more examples online.